# how to import swf in another one, added_to_stage? (as3, flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, import

i have a class `Team.as` that imports another class `CustomMenu.as`. This works fine, when i launch Team.fla, the content of CustomMenu appears well.

But, in my project, `Main.as` imports `Team.swf`, and then the content of `Team` appears on screen EXCEPT the content of `CustomMenu.as`.

So, i added a `ADDED_TO_STAGE` to the three of them, by example :

```
    public function Team() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initStage);
    }

    public function initStage(e:Event){
```

But CustomMenu never appears in the loader. It's not a problem with the size of the container, or anything like that, because i tried to put a black rectangle in the loaded swf and it works. Do you have any solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is initStage(e:Event) called when you addChild(myTeam); in your main project file?

You can just write some public init() method in Team class. Then cast your loaded content in main file to Team(loadedSWF), then call Team(loadedSWF).init() when you make sure it's already on the stage.

Comment: thanks rincewind for your quick answer, actually i understood what was going wrong, the swf was added at the very bottom of my main swf, so i couldn't see it... Just one question though, i tried the same thing, but this time i wanted to have my classes (except the main one) in a folder, let's say `TeamFolder`, but i couldn't load the swf `CustomMenu`, because of problem with the URL. i tried to change the url in `Team.as` in "/TeamFolder/CustoMenu.as", but neither that nor "CustomMenu.as" let me fix the problem. In such case, how would you do? Thanks a lot, Cheers

Comment: "/TeamFolder/CustomMenu.as"? You cannot load .as file via URL request (that makes no sense), so probably there's some mistake and you wanted to use .swf extension. When loading swf A file into another (B) you should use relative path (basing on B location). That's all I can say, if you need more please describe your problem in more details :).

Comment: thanks, sorry i forgot about this topic. I just put all the files in the same folder, to make things easier... thanks for your help anyway